# Prevent Flask jsonify from sorting the data

Tags: python, json, flask

Each time I use `jsonify`, I get the JSON keys sorted alphabetically. I don't want the keys sorted. Can I disable the sorting done in `jsonify`?

```
from flask import request, jsonify

@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def index():
    json_dict = request.get_json()
    user_id = json_dict['user_id']
    permissions = json_dict['permissions']
    data = {'user_id': user_id, 'permissions': permissions}
    return jsonify(data)
```

Comment: Why don't you want sorted data? It's still structured the same and doesn't make much difference.

Comment: Yeah, you wouldn't happen to be relying on the order of keys in your JSON, are you?

Comment: Because I wanted to know if that is possible to achieve as I wanna explore and quite pedantic

Comment: If you're passing in a dict, it already has undefined order, so there's no way to get "the values as sent".

Comment: Well, in the spirit of being pedantic, JSON objects *are unordered collections* according to [the spec](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt).

Answer (score 100, accepted):

Yes, you can modify this using the `config` attribute:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['JSON_SORT_KEYS'] = False
```

However, note that this is warned against explicitly in the [documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/config/#config):

> By default Flask will serialize JSON objects in a way that the keys
>   are ordered. This is done in order to ensure that independent of the
>   hash seed of the dictionary the return value will be consistent to not
>   trash external HTTP caches. You can override the default behavior by
>   changing this variable. This is not recommended but might give you a
>   performance improvement on the cost of cacheability.

Comment: It should be noted as of Python 3.6, dicts retain their insertion order so the argument from the docs doesn't apply anymore in that general sense.

Comment: I think the answer should be updated because this is an important sidenote from @hynek.

Comment: @hynek still seems to work on my version at python v3.7.3 & Flask v1.1.1

Comment: Nobody said that it doesn’t work anymore;  just that the rational for sorting keys that is in the docs quote is nil nowadays. Leaving it there could be confusing to new users.

Comment: @hynek I need my dict be in reverse order based on keys..so i do the same and return the response..but when passed through jsonify its back to its same order. How can I overcome this issue?

Answer (score 5):

The `JSON_SORT_KEYS` config option from the accepted answer was deprecated in Flask 2.2 and removed in Flask 2.3.

As of Flask 2.2, the [recommended way](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.2.x/config/#JSON_SORT_KEYS) of disabling sorting is through the `app.json` provider:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.json.sort_keys = False
```

Comment: Thanks for the heads up and for a related question, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76134147/how-do-you-work-around-deprecated-prettyprint-regular-flask-setting question.

Answer (score 3):

For Flask 2.3+:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
flask.json.provider.DefaultJSONProvider.sort_keys = False
```

Comment: Hello, please don't just submit code in your answer(s), add some details as to why you think this is the optimal solution.

Comment: The code in this answer does not work on its own. It throws an error in the interpreter due to name error on "flask". I am using Flask 2.3.2 and just changed the original line in the top answer to this line.
An extra `import flask` is required (in my case, the default `json` package from Python is already imported).

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to change the configuration for your entire API, you can return an unsorted JSON response using a small function like this:

```
def make_unsorted_response(results_dict: dict, status_code: int):
    resp = make_response({}, status_code)
    j_string = json.dumps(results_dict, separators=(',', ':'))
    resp.set_data(value=j_string)
    return resp
```

I like using flask-restx, here's how I'd use this function:

```
@api.route('/test', endpoint='test')
@api.doc(params={}, description="test")
class Health(Resource):
    def get(self):
        my_dict = {'z': 'z value',
                   'w': 'w value',
                   'p': 'p value'}
        results_dict = {"results": my_dict}
        return make_unsorted_response(results_dict, 200)
```

When called it returns an unsorted response like this:

```
{"results":{"z":"z value","w":"w value","p":"p value"}}
```

The syntax is pretty much the same in Flask. I would also recommend you add some exception handling to the function if you decide to use it, I'm just showing a basic example.