# Arrange JSON output according to default column list using select all query in Flask

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, rest, api, flask

I'm a new user of Python language using Flask and I found this code which really helped me:

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify
from flaskext.mysql import MySQL

app = Flask(__name__)
mysql = MySQL()

# MySQL configurations
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_USER'] = 'root'
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] = 'root'
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_DB'] = 'salestracker'
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_HOST'] = 'localhost'

mysql.init_app(app)

@app.route('/')
def get():
    cur = mysql.connect().cursor()
    cur.execute('''select * from user''')
    r = [dict((cur.description[i][0], value)
              for i, value in enumerate(row)) for row in cur.fetchall()]
    return jsonify({'myCollection' : r})

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

The sample output of this using select all query is:

json

```
[
    {
        "password": "7a227ac2ce556856a52fe1834a4ad5c5",
        "userID": 1,
        "username": "paulpctech"
    },
    {
        "password": "b87f1349dd97b7103af20879537cc161",
        "userID": 2,
        "username": "paulgwaps"
    },
    {
        "password": "a0173455d056e14888648b5e2656c7d2",
        "userID": 3,
        "username": "kael"
    },
    {
        "password": "a0173455d056e14888648b5e2656c7d2",
        "userID": 4,
        "username": "jake"
    },
    {
        "password": "a0173455d056e14888648b5e2656c7d2",
        "userID": 5,
        "username": "jake"
    }
]
```

What I want is to arrange the JSON output the same way that how I arranged my columns in tables. I want to see this output:

```
[
    {
        "userID": 1,
        "username": "paulpctech",
        "password": "7a227ac2ce556856a52fe1834a4ad5c5"
    },
    {
        "userID": 2,
        "username": "paulgwaps",
        "password": "b87f1349dd97b7103af20879537cc161"
    },
    {
        "userID": 3,
        "username": "kael",
        "password": "a0173455d056e14888648b5e2656c7d2"
    },
    {
        "userID": 4,
        "username": "jake",
        "password": "a0173455d056e14888648b5e2656c7d2"
    },
    {
        "userID": 5,
        "username": "jake",
        "password": "a0173455d056e14888648b5e2656c7d2"
    }
]
```

How can I change the output order?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
app.config['JSON_SORT_KEYS'] = False
```

[Also check out this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43263356/prevent-flask-jsonify-from-sorting-the-data).