# how to keep order of sorted dictionary passed to jsonify() function?

Tags: python, flask

I'm trying to pass sorted dictionary to jsonify() function and then use it from within JS code to take out values. What I see there is that even though I pass correct values, they are reordered by jsonify for some reason.

```
json_data = {
    "11": {
        "j_id": "out",
    },
    "aa": {
        "j_id": "in",
    },
    "bb": {
        "j_id": "out",
    },
}

jkeys=json_data.keys()
sorted_json = sorted(jkeys, key=lambda x: json_data[x]['j_id'], reverse=False)

new_sorted=OrderedDict()
for rec in sorted_json:
    new_sorted[rec]=json_data[rec]

print('sort dict: {}'.format(new_sorted))
```

The output is correct and I can see proper values which in my case should be: aa, 11, bb

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>>
>>> json_data = {
...     "11": {
...         "j_id": "out",
...     },
...     "aa": {
...         "j_id": "in",
...     },
...     "bb": {
...         "j_id": "out",
...     },
... }
>>>
>>> jkeys=json_data.keys()
>>> sorted_json = sorted(jkeys, key=lambda x: json_data[x]['j_id'], reverse=False)
>>>
>>> new_sorted=OrderedDict()
>>> for rec in sorted_json:
...     new_sorted[rec]=json_data[rec]
...
>>> print('sort dict: {}'.format(new_sorted))
sort dict: OrderedDict([('aa', {'j_id': 'in'}), ('11', {'j_id': 'out'}), ('bb', {'j_id': 'out'})])
```

Unfortunately, when I pass this to jsonify() function and then for example console.log() output of flask data, the orderd becomes like that: 11, aa, bb. Additionally to that, I've done some research and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43263356/prevent-flask-jsonify-from-sorting-the-data) stackoverflow answer, leading to some [good documentation notes](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/config/#config) which clearly states that setting *JSON_SORT_KEYS* to *False* is not recommended way. Then I checked [this github issue](https://github.com/pallets/flask/issues/974) and it seems that problem is not fully resolved in flask.

What would be the best way to fix it in my case?

Comment: JSON objects are *not ordered structures*. If you need to give things a specific order, use a list.

Comment: Serialising an `OrderedDict` to JSON produces a JSON document with the order preserved, but that doesn't mean that a Javascript client that decodes from JSON again won't drop your ordering. You *have* to use `app.config["JSON_SORT_KEYS"] = False` if you feel specifying the order is important anyway.

Comment: There really is no "problem" here. JSON objects have no order. You shouldn't write code that relies on any particular order of data serialized to JSON objects. If you need order, use a JSON array.

Comment: Try reviewing changes to a 30,000 line swagger.json API spec, then tell me that order is not important ;)   We use the sorting features of  https://github.com/thim81/openapi-format to take care of the problem.

Answer (score 116, accepted):

Add this config line to your code after the app definition:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['JSON_SORT_KEYS'] = False
```

**Update:** For Flask 2.3 and later use this:

```
app.json.sort_keys = False
```

Comment: thank you and that is absolutely insane that false is not the default

Comment: Awesome! Agree with @yigal that this should be set as default

Comment: @yigal I thought so too, but the original commit where this was added gives a fairly good reason: ["Order JSON keys by default to avoid trashing HTTP caches"](https://github.com/pallets/flask/commit/77d293cf49e586f03fbea96d0bae237bc7ed230f)

Comment: Summary: For Flask pre-2.3, use `app.config['JSON_SORT_KEYS'] = False`. For Flask 2.3 and above, use `app.json.sort_keys = False`.

Comment: any option for google cloud function. because there is no app

Answer (score 16):

JSON objects are *unordered structures*, and your browser could easily end up discarding the order of your JSON keys again.

From the [JSON standard](http://json.org/):

> An object is an **unordered** set of name/value pairs.

Bold emphasis mine. To remain standards compliant, use a *list* (JSON array) to capture a specific order.

That said, Flask can be made to preserve the order you set with `OrderedDict`.

- Disable sorting app-wide, with [`JSON_SORT_KEYS = False`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/config/#JSON_SORT_KEYS).

  With this setting at the default `True`, `jsonify()` sorts keys to provide stable HTTP responses that are cacheable. The documentation warns against disabling this only to make you aware of the downside of setting this to `False`.

  However, if you are using Python 3.6 or newer this concern doesn't actually play because as of that version the built-in `dict` type also [preserves insertion order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1867861/dictionaries-how-to-keep-keys-values-in-same-order-as-declared/39537308#39537308), and so there is no problem with the order changing from one Python run to the next.
- Instead of using `jsonify()`, use `flask.json.dumps()` directly, and create your own `Response` object. Pass in `sort_keys=False`:

  ```
  from flask import json

  response = current_app.response_class(
      json.dumps(new_sorted, sort_keys=False),
      mimetype=current_app.config['JSONIFY_MIMETYPE'])
  ```

Comment: any option for google cloud function. because there is no app

Answer (score 15):

The solution to set `app.config['JSON_SORT_KEYS'] = False` no longer does the trick in the latest version of [Flask (2.3)](https://github.com/pallets/flask/commit/6650764e9719402de2aaa6f321bdec587699c6b2), nor does it in Flask's asyncio-based sibling [Quart](https://github.com/pallets/quart).

The new way to turn off sorting is to update the `sort_keys` attribute on the app's `JSONProvider` instance:

```py
from flask import Flask  # or from quart import Quart, etc.

app = Flask(__name__)
app.json.sort_keys = False
```

or if you're already using a custom `JSONProvider` subclass:

```py
from flask import Flask
from flask.json.provider import DefaultJSONProvider

class CustomJSONProvider(DefaultJSONProvider):
    sort_keys = False

app = Flask(__name__)
app.json = CustomJSONProvider(app)
```

Comment: any option for google cloud function. because there is no app

Answer (score 4):

By default, keys from json are sorted to true.
You need to override this in your project config as follows:

```
app.config['JSON_SORT_KEYS'] = False
```

Comment: any option for google cloud function. because there is no app

Answer (score 4):

Please refer to the Flask documentation [2.3.x changes](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.3.x/changes/) (Released: `2023-04-25`)

> The `JSON_AS_ASCII`, `JSON_SORT_KEYS`, `JSONIFY_MIMETYPE`, and `JSONIFY_PRETTYPRINT_REGULAR` config keys are removed.

Version `2.3.x` has `DefaultJSONProvider` class with a default parameter: `sort_keys = True`

[image: DefaultJSONProvider Class description]

To disable default JSON (`dict`) key sort:

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)
app.json.sort_keys = False
```

Comment: any option for google cloud function. because there is no app