# How to customize output in API?

Tags: python, sql, flask

I am making a simple API using Python and Flask Framework and I am getting the correct output, but the problem with output is that It come in alphabetical order and I want to customize it in specific order.

This is the code I wrote

[First part of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/buaWU.png)
[Second Part of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7rqcY.png)

Output I am getting

```
{
    "alma": None,
    "close": 1549.6,
    "date":2015-02-02,
    "high": 1556.7,
    "low": 1544.8,
    "name": "ACC",
    "open": 1554.9,
    "volume": 1441
  }
```

Output I want

```
{
    "name": "ACC",
    "date":2015-02-02,
    "open": 1554.9,
    "high": 1556.7,
    "low": 1544.8,
    "close": 1549.6,
    "volume": 1441
    "alma": None
  },
```

I want to change the Output format but I don't know how to do it, If anyone know pleas tell me.

Comment: Can you show is your code as (properly formatted) text instead of a link to an image. (Would make copy-and-paste possible.)

Comment: Please review [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Also, the required output does not represent a valid Python datum

Comment: Order in JSON does not really matter, but this Q&A might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76032364/10513287

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flask offers the following configuration:

```py
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['JSON_SORT_KEYS'] = False
```