# How do you work around deprecated PRETTYPRINT_REGULAR Flask setting?

Tags: python, flask

The [*Version 2.2.0*](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.2.x/changes/#version-2-2-0) Flask release notes mention that *PRETTYPRINT_REGULAR* setting is deprecated; however, there isn't an explanation for what to do instead. The Flask changelog links to [*pallets/flask#4692*](https://github.com/pallets/flask/pull/4692) pull request that also doesn't explain how to enable *PRETTYPRINT_REGULAR* excellent setting. Based on [*docs/config.rst*](https://github.com/pallets/flask/pull/4692/files#diff-f0a5822170a0cb40ccc8b537d36cac7e27a986d9911b3a08c03feab8f9a47a13R318) example, I guessed that `app.json.prettyprint_regular` attribute might work; however, that doesn't work.

Given *PRETTYPRINT_REGULAR* Flask setting is deprecated since version 2.2.0, how do you enable Flask to pretty print your flask.jsonify response?

Comment: For a related Hacker News discussion about Flask breaking changes, see https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=37944326 page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## TL;DR:

Add this to your Flask app code:

```py
app.json_provider_class.compact = False
```

---

So, I did some digging.

Flask seems to be moving towards being able to build and select your own [`JSONProvider`](https://github.com/pallets/flask/blob/5f4072423ec6ee0c71d5995bec41e59d044e7737/src/flask/json/provider.py#L18) object, which their interface for handling JSON processing.

They provide a default implementation, [`DefaultJSONProvider`](https://github.com/pallets/flask/blob/5f4072423ec6ee0c71d5995bec41e59d044e7737/src/flask/json/provider.py#L123), which will handle pretty-printing JSON unless you explicitly switch providers.

The behavior is described in the [source](https://github.com/pallets/flask/blob/5f4072423ec6ee0c71d5995bec41e59d044e7737/src/flask/json/provider.py#L209), but essentially, two conditions make `.jsonify()` pretty print:

- `DefaultJSONProvider.compact = False` (default is `None`), and
- `app.debug = True`, with the default setting for `DefaultJSONProvider.compact` as `None`

This seems to be the direction Flask is going? I'd appreciate feedback from others as time passes since at the time of writing `2.3.1` is only 3 days old. But it feels a bit weird.

---

I've wrapped everything up in a little example with nonsensical JSON that you can modify and test out for yourself:

```py
from flask import Flask, jsonify
from flask.json.provider import DefaultJSONProvider

app = Flask(__name__)

# Make it not compact (Default is `None`)
DefaultJSONProvider.compact = False
# same thing as above, different way of setting it:
app.json_provider_class.compact = False
# app.json_provider_class defaults to DefaultJSONProvider

@app.route('/')
def index():
  print(app.debug)
  data = {
      "id": 123456,
      "name": {
          "first": "Lorem",
          "last": "Ipsum"
      },
      "age": 25,
      "address": {
          "street": "123 Main St.",
          "city": "Lorem",
          "state": "Ipsum",
          "zip": "12345"
      },
      "email": "lorem.ipsum@example.com"
  }
  return jsonify(data)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  app.run('0.0.0.0')
  # or try `app.run('0.0.0.0', debug=True)`
```

Might be cool to try the different combos of the `.compact` and `app.debug`, I've listed a couple